# How to Cluster and create a timechart in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a field with `LogMsg` error messages That I am grouping based on similarities using *cluster*.

What I am trying to achieve is a display that will show a timeseries with the grouped error

```
index="my_index_here" LogLevel=ERROR
  | cluster showcount=t t=0.2 field=Message | eval "Error Count" = cluster_count
  | head 10 | timechart count("Error Count") By LogMsg span=60m
```

The Idea is this

1. Get all the error Messages `LogLevel=ERROR`
2. Group the items based on Message field `| cluster showcount=t t=0.2 field=Message | eval "Error Count" = cluster_count`
3. Get top 10 results `| head 10`
4. Draw a timechart `timechart count("Error Count") By LogMsg span=60m`. The time chart should have a plot of number different error messages generated from the cluster against time, something like

| Message | 8.00 | 9:00 | 10.00 | 11:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unable to authenticate | 90 | 40 | 30 | 60 |
| Another Error | 80 | 40 | 30 | 60 |
| Yet another error | 70 | 40 | 30 | 60 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| The 10th most frequent error | 50 | 40 | 30 | 60 |

My approach above is not working returning a blank plot,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to debug SPL is to execute one pipe at time and verify the results before adding the next pipe.

One thing I believe you'll discover is the `head` command ruins the timechart.  It's possible all of the top 10 results will be in the same hour so the results may be less than useful.

A common cause of a "blank plot" is a `stats` or `timechart` command that references a non-existent or null field.  You should discover which field is null during the debug.

FWIW, here's a run-anywhere query similar to yours that produces a plot.

```
index=_internal log_level=INFO 
| cluster showcount=t t=0.2 field=event_message 
| eval "Error Count" = cluster_count 
| head 10 
| timechart count("Error Count") By group span=60m
```